# Smart way of associating elements in the same position

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have three matrices combined into a cell (they are all the same sizes)

```
output{1} = [2 3
             4 5]

output{2} = [5 6
             2 9]

output{3} = [3 10
             2 4]
```

I want to create another cell associating elements in the same position

```
celledoutput{1} = [2 5 3]
celledoutput{2} = [4 2 2]
celledoutput{3} = [3 6 10]
celledoutput{4} = [5 9 4]
```

Of course, I can do it using a lot of for loops. Just loop over size(output{1},1) and size(output{1},2) and gradually build up celledoutput.

But is there any smart method of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), and some careful reshaping is one way:

```
n = numel(output{1});
m = numel(output);

mat2cell(reshape(cell2mat(output(:).'),n,m),ones(n,1),m)
```

yields

```
ans{1} =
     2     5     3

ans{2} =
     4     2     2

ans{3} =
     3     6    10

ans{4} =
     5     9     4
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!